# Send nullable Guid to WebApi Asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I have a web api end point with the declaration:

```
public async Task VisitorConnected(Guid? fingerprint, long property_id)
```

Sometimes I want to send `null` for the first parameter. I read on one of the threads to send it as `"null"` in a string quotation. However I'm getting:

```
System.IO.InvalidDataException: Error binding arguments. Make sure that the types of the provided values match the types of the hub method being invoked.
 ---> System.FormatException: The JSON value is not in a supported Guid format.
   at System.Text.Json.Utf8JsonReader.GetGuid()
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Converters.JsonConverterGuid.Read(Utf8JsonReader& reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
   at System.Text.Json.JsonPropertyInfoNullable`2.OnRead(JsonTokenType tokenType, ReadStack& state, Utf8JsonReader& reader)
   at System.Text.Json.JsonPropertyInfo.Read(JsonTokenType tokenType, ReadStack& state, Utf8JsonReader& reader)
```

I tried to look it up in https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Text.Json/src/System/Text/Json/Reader/Utf8JsonReader.TryGet.cs#L940 but it appears that the Json Parser is not handling this `null` case. How can i achieve this, my second best option is to send an empty Guid 000-00000000-00-000... from the javascript client, and check in the web api controller, but feels like a hack.

Comment: Did you try to omit `fingerprint` parameter? I mean, just don't send the parameter at all.

Comment: You could try setting a default value of `null` for your `fingerprint` argument and handle the null check within your method.

Comment: but i need to send the property_id along

Comment: Not sure this helps.. but JS represents Guids with the `string` type which is not nullable.  So you want to type it as a `string | null`.  Tldr, can you try sending from Postman?

Comment: Parameters with default values need to be on the end of your argument list. It won't change the behavior of your other arguments.

Comment: solution was actually way easier than expected, just send null from javascript in the function paramete

Comment: thanks all for the responses

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing your Web API method to the following:
`public async Task VisitorConnected(long property_id, Guid? fingerprint = null)`

This will allow setting `fingerprint` to null while leaving `property_id` as a required argument to your method.